# SharePoint 2010: How to determine in what mode SQL Server Reporting Services is installed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services, troubleshooting

SharePoint 2010 Standard farm.

How can I determine in what mode the SQL Server Reporting Services is installed?

When installing SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), you must choose the mode in which it is installed.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143736%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#selectinginstalloption

How can I see in what mode it was installed?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326407%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) shows you how to move from different modes. Guess you would see on step 6 what mode you are using now:

> Click Database Setup to open the Database Setup page. The page contains information about the database currently in use.[]

Comment: Hello Robert and thank you for your reply. For some reason I am unable to connect to my Database. This might be a permission problem, so I will have to get back to you when that is resolved.